# Почему не запускается PowerShell скрипт через батник?

Tags: cmd, bat, powershell

Создал батник который запускает такой powershell скрипт:

```
dir C:\Users\home64\Downloads\1a -file | sort -property name -Descending | %{$i=0} {$_.CreationTime = (Get-Date).AddDays($i); $i++}
```

**Код батника:**

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command "dir C:\Users\home64\Downloads\1a -file | sort -property name -Descending | %{$i=0} {$_.CreationTime = (Get-Date).AddDays($i); $i++}"

pause
```

**При запуске батника получаю ошибку:**

[image]

Где ошбка? Почему не выполняется PS скрипт?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выполнить через **powershell**:

```
powershell dir C:\Users\home64\Downloads\1a -file | sort -property name -Descending | %{$i=0} {$_.CreationTime = (Get-Date).AddDays($i); $i++}
```

Или через **start**+*powershell.exe*:

```
start powershell.exe dir C:\Users\home64\Downloads\1a -file | sort -property name -Descending | %{$i=0} {$_.CreationTime = (Get-Date).AddDays($i); $i++}
```